# Edit editText in DialogFragment after layout has been inflated

Tags: java, android

I have a custom `DialogFragment` class. In `OnCreateDialog` I inflate my view like so:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
builder.setView(myView);
```

I then capture the reference to my EditText:

```
mText = (EditText)myView.findViewById(R.id.mtext_id);
```

Everything works fine if I try to edit the editText from within the `onCreateDialog` method.

But if try to edit the editText from a different method in the same class, using the same captured reference, it doesn't work.

```
mText.setText("foo");
```

Produces the error `InvocationTargetException` with the cause `NullPointerException`.

I've tried using a new reference to the id, calling it from the parent Activity instead of the DialogFragment itself, always with the same result.

Edited to include more code:

The complete `onCreateDialog`

```
public class TimeInputFragment extends DialogFragment {

OnTimeEnteredListener myCallback;
View myView;
EditText mText;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()); 
  builder.setMessage("foo")
      .setPositiveButton("Start timer", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
          myCallback.callbackMethod();
        }
      })
      .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
          // Cancel
        }
      });
  LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
  myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_timeentry, null);
  builder.setView(myView);

  mText = (EditText)myView.findViewById(R.id.TimeDialogInput);  

  return builder.create();  
}
```

The complete method to edit the editText (in the same class as `onCreateDialog`

```
public void setDialogText(String text) {
  mText.setText(text);
}
```

And the code calling the fragment from the parent activity:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

void createDialog(String title) {
    TimeInputFragment mDialog = new TimeInputFragment();
    mDialog.show(fragmentManager);  
    mDialog.setDialogText(title);
}
```

Comment: We need to see more code, specifically where you are calling setText when you call it `from a different method in the same class`.

Comment: Could you post the full onCreateDialog?

Comment: Your other method that you are referencing it from probably happens before your onCreateDialog.  So the EditText is null at this point as it hasn't been instantiate yet.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I have added more more complete code to the original post